# how to change section on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new in css and html. I am trying to make one page project but I don't know how to change the section when I go down with scroll wheel of the mouse. Can anybody help me?

Here's the code:

```css
section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

section.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<section data-section="0" class="active">
  <h1>hello! I'm the first section!</h1>
</section>
<section data-section="1">
  <h2>Hello! I'm the second section!</h2>
</section>
<section data-section="2">
  <h2>Hello! I'm the third section!</h2>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want a single wheel scroll tick to correspond to a section change. Instead of using CSS scroll snapping or external libraries like jQuery, you can accomplish your goal with just a wheel listener.

The `currentSectionIndex - 1 >= 0` and `currentSectionIndex + 1 < sections.length` conditions prevent subsequent wheel scrolls from exceeding the number of HTML sections there are.

Please refer to the attached JavaScript as the solution as the HTML and CSS provided are unchanged.

```js
let sections = document.getElementsByTagName('section');
// tracks index of current section
let currentSectionIndex = 0;

document.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
  if (e.wheelDeltaY > 0 && currentSectionIndex - 1 >= 0) {
    // wheel up
    sections[currentSectionIndex].className = '';
    currentSectionIndex--;
    sections[currentSectionIndex].className = 'active';
  } else if (e.wheelDeltaY < 0 && currentSectionIndex + 1 < sections.length) {
    // wheel down
    sections[currentSectionIndex].className = '';
    currentSectionIndex++;
    sections[currentSectionIndex].className = 'active';
  }
});
```

```css
section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color:white;
  background-color: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
section.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<section data-section="0" class="active">
  <h1>hello! I'm the first section!</h1>
</section>
<section data-section="1">
  <h2>Hello! I'm the second section!</h2>
</section>
<section data-section="2">
  <h2>Hello! I'm the third section!</h2>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the best at jQuery but this can help I hope :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#body').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {

      var num = $('.active').attr('data-section');
      num--;
      if (num <= -1) {
        num = num + 3;
      }
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
      $('section[data-section="' + num + '"]').addClass('active');
    } else {

      var num = $('.active').attr('data-section');
      num++;
      if (num >= 3) {
        num = 0;
      }
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
      $('section[data-section="' + num + '"]').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

section.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="body">
  <section data-section="0" class="active">
    <h1>hello! I'm the first section!</h1>
  </section>
  <section data-section="1">
    <h2>Hello! I'm the second section!</h2>
  </section>
  <section data-section="2">
    <h2>Hello! I'm the third section!</h2>
  </section>
</body>
```